# when is finalize called when deployed on tomcat

Tags: java, file, tomcat, io, finalize

I have created a simple Java class as follows:

I pass content as a byte-array and a Filename and the class creates a TempFile somewhere.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class TempFile {

private byte[] content;
private File file;
private String fileName;

public TempFile(byte[] content, String fileName) 
        throws IOException {
    this.content = content;
this.fileName = fileName;
file = createTempFile();
}

private File createTempFile() 
        throws IOException {
    String tmpDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    if(!tmpDir.endsWith("/") || !tmpDir.endsWith("\\"))
        tmpDir += "/";
    File tmpfile = new File(tmpDir + createUniqueName());
    while(tmpfile.exists())
        tmpfile = new File(tmpDir + createUniqueName());
    tmpfile.createNewFile();
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(tmpfile, content);
    return tmpfile;
}

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    try {
        if(file.exists() && file.canRead() && file.canWrite())
            file.delete();
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```

}

I thought if I implemented the cleanup to happen in the finalize-method, the tempfiles would be automatically deleted when the GC disposes of the object.

I tried debugging this, but it seems the finalize method is not called.

What's the reason?  Could this be because I am deploying this a Tomcat server?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relying on `finalize` to clean up resources is a bad idea. You (normally) have no control over when garbage collection happens and when `finalize` is called. In fact, the JVM does not even guarantee at all that `finalize` will ever be called, so if for some reason it isn't, your resources won't be cleaned up at all.

Comment: Yeah really the only reason to use finalizers I can think of is to have some sanity checks in there while developing.

Answer (score 1):

Do not rely on the finalizer (that's one item in Effective Java). Invoke the cleanup manually.